# Roots Of Unity Proof On Concurrent Lines

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, roots-of-unity

Let $P_1 P_2 \dotsb P_{18}$ be a regular 18-gon. Show that $P_1 P_{10}$, $P_2 P_{13}$, and $P_3 P_{15}$ are concurrent.

---

When positioned on the unit circle, I know that $P_1 P_{10}$ is the diameter.  I also know that if $p$ and $q$ are points on the unit circle such that the line through $p$ and $q$ intersects the real axis and if $z$ is the point where this line intersects the real axis, then $z = \dfrac{p+q}{pq+1}$.  So I should let $P_1 P_{10} be on the real axis.  Where should I go from now?  Thanks.

Comment: I posted an algebraic answer using complex numbers [under the other question](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2137532/291201).